# Is WPF easy to learn when compared to other languages?

Tags: wpf

Is WPF easy to learn when compared to other languages?. Or should the Approach towards WPF learning be changed in comparison with other languages?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, first of all - WPF is anything BUT a langauge. WHat you ask is like "is it hard to learn GIF compared to other langauges".

The "langauge" behind WPF is XAML - and XAML is not hard to learn TECHNICALLY, but making sense out of the hundreds of objects and variations of approaches is not exactly easy. It is akin to HTML and CSS and Javascript in one system, standardized - but supercharged.

Expect first results fast, then some really hard way up to the next levels.

Answer (score 1):

WPF is framework, not language. It is little bit harder to learn indeed, but if you see way how to profit from this knowledge, invest your time and learn it. It's one of the best GUI frameworks ATM and for next few years it'll be on very top.

Answer (score 1):

For me the hardest part about WPF is navigating the insane myriad of ways there is to accomplish something. Even for simple stuff there can be quite a few ways to do it. And I havent (yet) found a "right" or "correct" way to work with WPF, a WPF philosophy if you like.

Oh, and the designer/preview for WPF in Visual Studio is so slow its quite hard... at least on  me. Be wary of that. ;)

Comment: Indeed. Best visual GUI designer I've worked with is Swing designer in NetBeans. It beats even VS's WPF designer, which didn't amaze me so much ...

Answer (score 1):

Speaking from a trainer perspective, WPF is complex, so it can be tricky to learn when poorly explained.

It involves learning XAML and it many cases MVVM. If you want to learn quickly about both WPF and the MVVM pattern, read this book: [Learn WPF MVVM](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01M365NCZ).